# WSO2 API Manager can't reach the Production endpoint

Tags: proxy, wso2-api-manager

I was able to publish the API.

But when I try to test the service through the API Manager URI, the API manager return the following message "INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender"

I followed all steps, and I generated the susbcriptions and keys neeeded, even more, I tried with other security token, or with other kind of SLA, and the API manager gave me a correct message: token invalid, or token expired, or number of requests exceded, BUT when the request is good (token, etc.), the response is bad "INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender"

Any idea to solve this issue, I was reviewing the log, and the unique trace is the trace indicated in this topic "INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender" "ERROR {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil} -  #toXml. Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input. Error>>> null {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-21 14:44:03,223] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder} -  Error building message {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder}"

I have given following sequence in my synapse.xml

```
 <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
    <property name="Proxy-Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:password'))" scope="transport"/>
    <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
 </sequence>
```

and I have also added the following properties in my axis2.xml

```
 <parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">proxyName.company.com</parameter>
 <parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">1234</parameter>
 <parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">localhost</parameter>
```

Please advise ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a POST request to the gateway without any payload? If the content-type is application/json then try to send a empty json payload like "{}"

Also you could enable the wirelogs to do more debuging. http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html . you could get an idea about your error by evaluating the request-response flow